# Using Vlookup, but there is a formula in the array cell, what can I do?

Tags: excel, vlookup, trim

I have used another formula to make a answer, then I need to use vlookup me make another answer such as pictures, actually theere is a formula in cell "CG16", I wanna do a vlookup like the blue frame, means when the red frame is 10:00-18:00, the cell "#VALUE!" is showing 10:00-14:00

I have tried to do ---> VLOOKUP(VALUE(TRIM(, but it does not work, please kindly help how to solve this question, thank you so much!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/do30r.jpg]

Comment: 1.  VALUE is used to turn text into numbers, but `10:00-18:00` is a string that cannot be converted.  remove the VALUE.  2.  The third criterion is `4`,  there are only two columns in the lookup range, the max that number can be is `2`.

Comment: Hi scott craner, 
It works now, I use basic vlookup for 
=VLOOKUP(CG16,CJ:CK,2,FALSE) to done for it